# How can I make my custom shell work with ssh?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, stdio

I'm making a custom shell in Python for a very limited user on a server, who is logged in via ssh with a public key authentication. They need to be able to run `ls`, `find -type d`, and `cat` in specific directories with certain limitations. This works fine if you run something like `ssh user@server -i keyfile`, because you see the interactive prompt, and can run those commands. However, something like `ssh user@server -i keyfile "ls /var/log"` doesn't. `ssh` simply hangs, with no response. By using the `-v` switch I've found that the connection is succeeding, so the problem is in my shell. I'm also fairly certain that the script isn't even being started, since `print sys.argv` at the beginning of the program does nothing. Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import re
import os

with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
    proc = lambda x: subprocess.Popen(x, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=devnull)

    while True:
        try:
            s = raw_input('> ')
        except:
            break

        try:
            cmd = re.split(r'\s+', s)
            if len(cmd) != 2:
                print 'Not permitted.'
                continue
            if cmd[0].lower() == 'l':
                # Snip: verify directory
                cmd = proc(['ls', cmd[1]])
                print cmd.stdout.read()
            elif cmd[0].lower() == 'r':
                # Snip: verify directory
                cmd = proc(['cat', cmd[1]])
                print cmd.stdout.read()
            elif cmd[0].lower() == 'll':
                # Snip: verify directory
                cmd = proc(['find', cmd[1], '-type', 'd'])
                print cmd.stdout.read()
            else:
                print 'Not permitted.'
        except OSError:
            print 'Unknown error.'
```

And here's the relevant line from ~/.ssh/authorized_keys:

```
command="/path/to/shell $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" ssh-rsa [base-64-encoded-key] user@host
```

How can I make the shell script when the command is passed on the command line so it can be used in scripts without starting an interactive shell?

Comment: Check out /etc/passwd. The last field is the path to the shell to be used by the user. You could setup a test user and have that user's shell be your shell for testing. Then you wouldn't have to keep calling your shell with commands.

Comment: For some reason, modifying /etc/passwd the way you suggest breaks public key login, even when the `command` part of authorized_keys isn't there. I'm not sure I understand why that could happen. Perhaps SELinux didn't like it?

Comment: Possibly your shell is exiting prematurely. An old prank to pull on *nix users was to set people's shell to `false`, so they couldn't log in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with ssh not responding is related to the fact that `ssh user@host cmd` does not open a terminal for the command being run. Try calling `ssh user@host -t cmd`.

However, even if you pass the `-t` option, you'd still have another problem with your script: it only works interactively and totally ignores the $SSH_ORIGINAL_PROGRAM being passed. A naive solution would be to check `sys.argv` and if its bigger than 1 you don't loop forever, and instead only execute whatever command you have in it.